# Why does Hong Kong approve just 2 out of 7 triptans?

Tags: discussion

How to make https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20161/16910 on topic?

---

Since the question was removed (close vote by 1 mod + Stack Exchange's automated question deletion system), here is a copy of it:

> Why does Hong Kong approve just 2 out of 7 triptans?
>
> [The Drug
>   Office](https://www.drugoffice.gov.hk/eps/drug/productSearchOneFieldAction)
>   website lists just 2 triptans — sumatriptan, zolmitriptan.  Why?   I'm
>   unnerved — picking the right triptan is issue of its own, and so
>   little choice means some Hongkongers aren't being treated.
>
> [image]
>
> But [7 triptans are available in North
>   America](https://www.medicinenet.com/migraine/article.htm):
>
> > 1. [sumatriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/sumatriptan/article.htm)
> >        ([Imitrex](https://www.medicinenet.com/sumatriptan/article.htm),
> >        [Alsuma](https://www.medicinenet.com/sumatriptan/article.htm), Imitrex
> >        STATdose System, Sumavel DosePro,
> >        [Zecuity](https://www.medicinenet.com/sumatriptan_iontophoretic_transdermal_system/article.htm),
> >        Treximet)
> > 2. [rizatriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/rizatriptan_tablet-oral/article.htm)
> >        ([Maxalt](https://www.medicinenet.com/rizatriptan_tablet-oral/article.htm),
> >        Maxalt-MLT)
> > 3. [eletriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/eletriptan/article.htm) ([Relpax](https://www.medicinenet.com/eletriptan/article.htm))
> > 4. [zolmitriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/zolmitriptan/article.htm)
> >        ([Zomig](https://www.medicinenet.com/zolmitriptan/article.htm),
> >        [Zomig-ZMT](https://www.medicinenet.com/zolmitriptan/article.htm))
> > 5. [naratriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/naratriptan-oral/article.htm)
> >        ([Amerge](https://www.medicinenet.com/naratriptan-oral/article.htm))
> > 6. [almotriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/almotriptan-oral/article.htm)
> >        ([Axert](https://www.medicinenet.com/almotriptan-oral/article.htm))
> > 7. [frovatriptan](https://www.medicinenet.com/frovatriptan-oral/article.htm)
> >        ([Frova](https://www.medicinenet.com/frovatriptan-oral/article.htm))
>
> By the way, HK also hasn't approved Erenumab (Aimovig).

Comment: You really can't make it on topic for this stack, and I'm not sure it's on topic anywhere else on the exchange, either. You're asking about a singular governments' policies. Your best bet are local representatives/medical professionals that might be able to answer it.

Comment: [Are questions about drug approvals on-topic?](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/403/43)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt i up-voted you! i think yes.

Comment: @MatthewLau same!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt What category would this fall under in [the list of on-topic subjects](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)? As I said in my comments on the question, drug approval questions _might_ fall under the heading of public health, but the core of this particular question isn't about public health. Like John said above, it's about a single government's policies and their internal reasoning behind those policies, which are quite possibly primarily political.

Comment: @CareyGregory I'm hoping that most decisions for drug approvals aren't solely based on politics. But in the case they are, then the proper answer is could simply state so, and political discussions could head to politics SE.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You didn't respond to my question. What category of on-topic subjects does this fall under? I would add that if answering a question here requires poring over the minutes of government committee meetings, it's almost certainly off-topic.